# Use of unresolved identifier GGLContext and GAI

Tags: xcode, swift, google-analytics, swift2

I am having a bit of trouble.  I am attempting to install Google Analytics into an app and am consistently getting the use of unresolved identifier `GGLContext` and `GAI` error.  I receive the same error whether I am using CocoaPods or not. The location of the error is in the `AppDelegate.swift` here:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    // Optional: configure GAI options.
    let gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
    gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions

    return true
}
```

Nothing additional is able to be imported into the `AppDelegate.swift`(such as Google), just the standard `UIKit`.

I have been through many tutorials and other SO questions, all to no avail.  I figure that there is some small thing I am missing, but cannot find it.

What I've done:

I have the `.h` files in my project, along with `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a`, `libsqlite3.0.tbd`, `libz.tbd`, `libsqlite3.tbd` (all of which have been linked to library as well as CoreData and SystemConfiguration).

You can see the layout of all these files here:

[image]

and here:

[image]

I have created the `-Bridging-Header.h` and included these `.h` imports in it.

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceFields.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProduct.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProductAction.h"
#import "GAIEcommercePromotion.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAILogger.h"
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
```

The `-Bridging-Header.h` is linked in the Build Settings and I receive no errors with that.  That is the main solution that I have found during my research, which hasn't helped me in this situation.

I have tried to start over from scratch twice with CocoaPods and without (I made a copy of my project before starting) and I received the same error each time.

Any help would certainly be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it looks like I was able to get it squared away.

There were several problems with all attempts on this.

1. Cocoapods had not installed correctly.  I reinstalled and then had better success importing the correct files.
2. Doing it manually, as I posted above is not the best option.
3. After the Cocoapods re-install and starting over from a fresh copy of my project, I was able to `import Google` into my `AppDelegate.swift`.

Key points for those who may end up in the same boat I was in:

- Be sure to add the correct directory for your `-Bridging-Header.h`.  You can find this under Project - Build Settings - Swift Compiler Code Generation.  Use this to easily target your header file `$(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h`
- In your `-Bridging-Header.h`, do not `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`, instead import the files individually.  Here is an image of the files available to be imported.

[image]

- When in doubt, reinstall Cocoapods
- Do not trust Google tutorials to provide the most effective instruction and utilize the many SO posts on the topic.

I really hope this helps someone not spend 10 hours on the problem as I have.

Comment: I followed this including re-checking-out my project and everything thing is fine now. Hours upon hours, and it seems that cocoapods installed incorrectly or something (perhaps incorrectly set the build settings). From scratch I pod init, added the " pod 'Google/Analytics' " and "pod install"'d - created the bridging header, added all of the individual files (cut and pasted from initial question near the bottom) - pointed build settings to the bridging header - now import Google works in AppDelegate and the bridging header isn't complaining about <Google/Analytics.h> being not found!

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 4.0 and xcode 9.0.1 finally I resolved.**

For me after 2 days I resolved.. Don't follow Google's old documentation says `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`

1. Go to Terminal type `pod init`
2. Reopen project as workspace obvious after pod workspace is created, open podfile. write `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'` in your pod file before `target 'GoogleAnalytics' do`
3. Go back to Terminal `pod install` you will find frameworks `GAI.h` and other files will be there under pods folder
4. Create `Header.h` file to your root. ***Don't add `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`*** instead import following individually in bridging header file

e.g. in bridging header file remove `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`

```
#import GAI.h
#import "GAITracker.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
```

5. Point your bridge under Build Settings for target Swift Compiler - General -> Objective-C Bridging Header. write `Header.h` of your bridging file name
6. Add code from google for swift to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` **Don't forget to replace your tracking id from Google Analytics page**

   ```
       guard let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() else {
           assert(false, "Google Analytics not configured correctly")
       }
       gai.tracker(withTrackingId: "YOUR_TRACKING_ID")
       // Optional: automatically report uncaught exceptions.
       gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true

       // Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
       // Remove before app release.
       gai.logger.logLevel = .verbose;
   ```

Tada.... Run your project...

Answer (score 9):

My error was use of unresolved identifier when i was using the singleton `GAI.sharedInstance()`.

My steps to bring this to work were:

1. add  `pod 'Google/Analytics'`
2. pod install
3. restart xcode
4. create a objc class in my project to get a bridging header
5. added `#import "GAI.h"` in to the bridging header file

everything works perfectly.

Comment: I installed 'GoogleAnalytics' pod But I having problem with that can you help me please ? 
here is the link of my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49093139/pod-googleanalytics-in-swift-4-wont-run

Answer (score 9):

This works for swift 2.3, swift 3.0 and swift 4:

1. add the GoogleService-Info.plist file to the root of your project
2. add this to the podfile:

   ```
     pod 'Google/Analytics'
   ```
3. quit Xcode, run "pod install" in terminal and open Xcode again
4. create a header file in the project root, named Bridging-Header.h, under build settings make sure the bridging header is defined like in the picture
   [image]
5. make sure your Bridging-Header.h looks like this:

   ```
     #ifndef Bridging_Header_h
     #define Bridging_Header_h
     #import <Google/Analytics.h> 
     #endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
   ```
6. add to AppDelegate:

   ```
   import Google
   ```
7. add this code to AppDelegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

   ```
   // Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
   var configureError: NSError?
   GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)

   assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services:\(configureError)")

   // Optional: configure GAI options.
   guard let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() else {
       assert(false, "Google Analytics not configured correctly")
   }
   gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions
   gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose  // remove before app release
   ```

If there are errors, deleting DerivedData and cleaning the project can help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make it work for me was downgrade Google Analytics pod version to 2.0.4.

pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 2.0.4'